# How could I create a template in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

In my ReactJS app I have a lot of Routes (React-Router dependency). They are sub-divided in `alumno` and `admin`. Both the student and admin template have a few common elements.

- In the case of student: Header, student menu, CONTENT, footer;
- In the case of administrator: Header, student menu, CONTENT, footer;

So, in this example, I would have to have two templates, one for student and one for administrator. How could I create a template where only the CONTENT was dynamic and the rest static?. In other words, CONTENT would be what React-Router loads me (dynamic), while both header, menu and footer remains for all pages (it's for all the same, no reloading, static).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not have the concept of `templates`, in react the data is tied to the view in a single component, the closest to a template would be a simple/dumb/presentational component that you can pass properties into. you can make these properties as complex or plain as you want. But it will never be just html or anything else it will always have to be a component. you can learn more about it [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Comment: Wow ... This question came to me because every time a route is loaded, when the elements are re-mounted, they lose their previous states, resetting the ones they have by default, having to go through the props properties that I want to save. If you can make a 'template' that is not mounted and dismantled with each route, this could be avoided.

Comment: take a few minutes and reason over what you just said. a template is just a template, the data would be held separately  and besides if a route changes and the prop changes shouldn't your component loose all the data? it feels like you are not giving all the details, in any case the answer remains the same, seems to me you have a hard time understanding how react works or ho to architect your application. what data flow library are you using? redux? reflux? flux? mcfly? alt? if you need more help, you might want to reframe the question. for this one i don't think you'll get a different answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I'm not using any, at the moment it is not useful. Possibly use Redux in the future.

Comment: in that case you would be good using react-router-redux, and don't make it an afterthought, it will help you architect your app if you start using it right away. my rule is that if your app is big enough that you need a router then you should start using a data flow lib